# firefox is adding space after footer tag

Tags: html, css, firefox, footer

This is not happening in chrome or ie. Firefox instead is adding 50px after my footer. with analyze element and firebug it is showing that that space is outside html tags. here is the link: http://www.sociallab.ro/index_romana
Thanks!

html:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="main">
  </div>
  <footer>
    <a href="http://www.messagelab.ro" target="_blank"><div class="message_lab"><img src="images/logo_mic.png" alt="Tineret in Actiune"/></div></a>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html{ 
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
footer{position:relative; 
 top: -50px; 
width:1060px; 
height:50px; 
overflow:hidden;
text-align: center;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;}
body{
     margin-top:0px;
     margin:0 auto;
     padding:0;
     text-align: center;
     height: 1950px !important; 
background:url(../images/bg.png) left top repeat; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A few things:

1. There should not be a `<div>` tag inside `<a>` tag.
2. There is a `height` for `body` and `#wrap`.
3. For the `footer`, please remove the `top: -50px;` and replace it with negative `margin` as `margin-top: -50px;`.

#### To make the footer link align center

Without using div, use this way:

```
<footer>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.messagelab.ro">
        <img alt="Tineret in Actiune" src="images/logo_mic.png">
    </a>
</footer>
```

And CSS:

```
footer a {display: block; text-align: center;}
```

Comment: First thing is, when you say between `position` and `margin`, yeah, go for `margin`. And, do not nest block level elements inside inline elements.

Answer (score 2):

Insted of using top:-50px, use margin-top:-50 px on the footer and the problem is solved.